# Unable to build the JSON with mydata

Tags: jquery

My Screen looks this way

[image]

There are 2 Items in the screen .

For Item 1 ===> Honey with Butter is selected

For Item 2 ===> Nutts and dry fruits10 gm is selected

Based on this i am trying to build below JSON as shown

```
[
    {
        "name": "Item 1",
        "value": [
            "None",
            "Honey with Butter"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Item 2",
        "value": [
            "Nutts and dry fruits10 gm",
            "None"
        ]
    }
]
```

I Have tried it this way

```
var toppings = [];



 $('.tdHeading').each(function () {
                values = [];
                $(this).each(function () {
                    if($(this).hasClass('tpActive'))
                    {

                        alert($(this).attr('topp_name'))
                         values.push($(this).attr('topp_name'));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         values.push('None');
                    }

                });
                if(values.length>0)
                {
                    toppings.push({
                        'name': $(this).text().trim(),
                        'value': values
                    });
                }
            });


console.log(JSON.stringify(toppings));
```

But i am getting the below o/p

```
[
    {
        "name": "Item  1",
        "value": [
            "None"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Item  2",
        "value": [
            "None"
        ]
    }
]
```

please help how to resolve this

http://jsfiddle.net/7xdqvaay/1/

Comment: no class `tpActive` in markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look for siblings children :

```
  $(this).siblings().each(function () {
                    if($(this).children().hasClass('tpActive'))
                    {
                        alert($(this).children('.tpActive').attr('topp_name'))
                         values.push($(this).children('.tpActive').attr('topp_name'));
                    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7xdqvaay/12/

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for children of your h6 headings. There are none. All the sections are siblings of one another. i.e.

```
<aside>
    <h6>A heading with no children</h6>
    <section><a>At the same hierarchical as the heading and the next section</a></section>
    <section><a>ditto</a></section>
</aside>
...
```

You should iterate each `$('aside')` element to fix this. e.g. 
http://jsfiddle.net/7xdqvaay/11/

Then use find to handle h6 and anchor child elements.

Comment: Thanks for finding out my mistake .But why None is not coming ( I mean the  else condition .hasClass('tpActive') ??

Comment: That's an error. I thought you didn't want the none matching entries.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, it needs to be in list form:

```
<ul class="tdHeading">
  <li class="name">Item 1</li>
  <li class="value tpActive">...</li>
</ul>
```

Watch how you loop, I would recommend:

```
$('.tdHeading').each(function () {
    $(this).find('.value').each(function () { ... });
    ...
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the trouble , I dont have right to modify CSS , as its Written by others , How can i make it work with same thing as in fiddle